# logistic regression error message in r

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I can't resolve a message error in my logit model.

This is my data:

[image]

My dummy variable is `CreativeOutputs`. All variables are numeric and without NA.

My code for the logit model:

```
logit2 <- glm(CreativeOutputs ~. , family=binomial(link="logit"), data=b )
```

The error message:

> logit2 <- glm(CreativeOutputs ~. , family=binomial(link="logit"), data=b ) Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :    attempt to
>   use zero-length variable name

Any solution?

Comment: When asking for help, it's best if you include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data (not a picture) that we can use to copy/paste into R to run and test what's going on.

Comment: As the screenshot shows, the first columns' name is empty. Try `logit2 <- glm(CreativeOutputs ~. , family=binomial(link="logit"), data=b[,-1] )`.